# Spaces between div's

Tags: css

```
div.one{
   Border:1px solid;
   Padding:25px 50px 75px;
   Background-color:lightblue;
}
div.two{
   Border:1px solid;
   Padding:25px 50px;         
   Background-color:lightblue;
}
div.three{
   Border:1px solid;
   Padding:25px;          
   Background-color:rgb(33,56,78);
}
```

And the div is appearing one after another i want spaces betwwen the three divs how can i put the spaces between divs actully i am learning css

*how can i add spaces between three divs**

Comment: There are lots of ways, have you had a look at the available properties? (Also, CSS property names start with lower case letters and do not contain spaces)

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. please take a moment and read this article https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask about how to asking questions also read this article https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example about how to ask a good question with minimum requirement.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `margin` to give a space between the div's which is the easiest and issueless way to do this.

Check this snippet.

```css
div {
  border: 1px solid;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

div.one {
  padding: 25px 50px 75px;
  background-color: lightblue;
}
div.two {
  padding: 25px 50px;
  background-color: lightblue;
}

div.three {
  padding: 25px;
  background-color: rgb(33, 56, 78);
}
```

```html
<div class="one">One</div>
<div class="two">Two</div>
<div class="three">Three</div>
```